# deserializing the json string to object in c# (Newtonsoft.Json)

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I want to deserialize the json string into c# object  which is of the following format

```
[{
"data": "{\"SecureId\":null,\"FNAME\":\"WILL\",\"MNAME\":null,\"LNAME\":\"CLINTON\",\"POSTNAME\":\"Mrs.\",\"DOB\":\"6/10/1997\",\"GENDER\":\"M\",\"ORGID\":null}",
"isAvial": true,
"details": "55",
"id": "1999089"}, {
"data": "{\"SecureId\":null,\"FNAME\":\"RIN\",\"MNAME\":null,\"LNAME\":\"MANN\",\"POSTNAME\":\"Jr\",\"DOB\":\"9/16/1997\",\"GENDER\":\"F\",\"ORGID\":null}",
"isAvial": true,
"details": "P2145",
"id": "1999090"}, {
"data": "{\"SecureId\":null,\"FNAME\":\"RIN\",\"MNAME\":null,\"LNAME\":\"MANNING\",\"POSTNAME\":\"M.D.\",\"DOB\":\"9/16/1997\",\"GENDER\":\"F\",\"ORGID\":null}",
"isAvial": true,
"details": "205",
"id": "1999091"}, {
"data": "{\"SecureId\":null,\"FNAME\":\"David\",\"MNAME\":null,\"LNAME\":\"O'PETER\",\"POSTNAME\":\"Dr\",\"DOB\":\"9/6/1997\",\"GENDER\":\"M\",\"ORGID\":null}",
"isAvial": true,
"details": "PM25",
"id": "1999092"}]
```

I have tried the following but it didn't worked. I'm using Newtonsoft.json

```
public class DataObj
{
    public string isAvial { get; set; }
    public string details { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public DataTable data { get; set; }
}
public class JsonOutput
{
    public List<DataObj> DetailsObj { get; set; }
}

var desc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonOutput>>(jsonstring);
```

thanks for help..

Comment: I think all you need is: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DataObj>>(jsonstring);`

Comment: the above method "JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DataObj>>(jsonstring)"  is working guys, but only if i change property data in class "DataObj"  to of type string. thanks...

Comment: The problem maybe that DataTable doesn't have a paremeterless constructor....

Answer (score 1):

Its failing because your JSON is an array but you are trying to deserialize to an object that contains an array instead of directly to an array or list. Also I have serious doubts that your property `data` can be deserialized as is, you will probably have to write custom code to deserialize a `DataTable` or you should change it to a generic list/collection using a custom type.

```
public class DataObj
{
    public string isAvial { get; set; }
    public string details { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    // public DataTable data { get; set; } // if this is the FCL defined DataTable you will not be able to deserialize it without some custom code. Better would be to have a strongly typed custom class 
}

var desc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DataObj>>(jsonstring);
```

Comment: yes this "data" property is actually causing not deserializing to a DataTable., but if i change type to string it is deserializing to a string thanks..

Answer (score 1):

If the format is correct in "data". Then this will solve

```
public class DataObj
{
    public string isAvial { get; set; }
    public string details { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public DataTable data { get; set; } 
} 
var desc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DataObj>>(jsonstring);
```

else separate parsing Datatable or something like this 
(DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonString, (typeof(DataTable)));

Comment: or try DeserializeObject "data" as string. And then try parsing string to datatable.!!

Answer (score 0):

In your JSON object, you have a list of DataObj objects, so (provided the DataTable class is described correctly according to the JSON structure) you should use the following to deserialize:

```
var desc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DataObj>>(jsonstring);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
public class dataC
{
    public int SecureId { get; set; }
    public string FNAME { get; set; }
    public string  MNAME { get; set; }
    public string LNAME { get; set; }
    public string POSTNAME { get; set; }
    public string DOB { get; set; }
    public string GENDER { get; set; }
    public int ORGID { get; set; }
}


public class DataObj
    {
        public dataC data { get; set; }
        public bool isAvial { get; set; }
        public string details { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
    }


JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DataObj>>(jsonstring);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your deserialzing class should be like

```
 public class RootObject
    {
        private object _data;

        public object data
        {
            get
            {
                return _data;
            }
            set
            {
                _data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dataS>(value.ToString());
            }
        }

        public bool isAvial { get; set; }
        public string details { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
    }

    public class dataS
    {
        public object SecureId { get; set; }
        public string FNAME { get; set; }
        public object MNAME { get; set; }
        public string LNAME { get; set; }
        public string POSTNAME { get; set; }
        public string DOB { get; set; }
        public string GENDER { get; set; }
        public object ORGID { get; set; }
    }
```

And serialization should be like

```
var tmp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
```